# Pin all local variables when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

When I am debugging, it is a pain to have to manually pin every variable so I can see its value in the text editor.

How can I *batch* pin all local variables in Visual Studio 2013 when debugging?

Comment: I don't think there's a way of doing this. Do keep in mind that pins are persistent across debugs (for a single instance of VS), so you only have to do this once if you're debugging a particularly tricky section of code. Also, I find it *substantially* more useful to use the "Locals", "Auto" and/or "Watch" windows to monitor the values of variables.

Comment: @CodyGray Interesting choice of words in the edit. Nevertheless if you turned your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I would have posted an answer if I knew for certain that there is no way. But I don't, and I'm curious if someone else knows if it is possible. That's why I only posted a comment, and upvoted your question.

Comment: @CodyGray Out of curiosity where do you keep your *Locals* and *Watch* windows relative to editor?

Comment: Docked at the bottom, underneath the text editor. Registers is on the far left and very small, Locals/Auto/Watch are stacked (as tabs) taking up the majority of the middle, and then Call Stack and some other useful stuff are grouped/tabbed on the right. This layout appears only when debugging; VS maintains separate "debug mode" and "design mode" edit layouts. I've tried having this stuff on a separate monitor, but that puts it too far away from the code for me.